# On a property of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be continous functions and $f(x)\neq 0$ forall $x$. Prove that $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$ forall $x$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ forall $x$ or $f(x)=-g(x)$ forall $x$.

It 'is so apparent, so I don't know what must I do, and with similar problems, do we have the general solution? Thank you!

Comment: Think about what might happen in the case where f is not continuous. It may give you some clues as to why continuous required in the question, and may help your construct your proof.

Comment: Without the assumption of continuity, it could be the case that $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f(y)=-g(y)$ for some other point $y$, which is what you are asked to show can't happen.

Comment: yeah, I got your hints, thankyou :D

Answer (score 1):

The continuous function $\frac g f$ takes only the values $-1$ and $+1$. What can you conclude from this?